# Counting all lines of code in .php files given a dir

Tags: php

How to make a little function that given a directory it returns the number of lines (counts `\r\n`) of `.php` files between `<?php and ?>`?

Usage:

```
echo countsLineOfCode('D:/dir/code/');    
// returns 323;
```

Comment: Please tell me you're NOT going to use this to measure how much work  your coders are doing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function countLinesOfCode($path) {
   $lines = 0;
   $items = glob(rtrim($path, '/') . '/*');

   foreach($items as $item) {

       if (is_file($item) AND pathinfo($item, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'php') {
           $fileContents = file_get_contents($item);
           preg_match_all('/<\?(?:php)?(.*?)($|\?>)/s', $fileContents, $matches);

           foreach($matches[1] as $match) {
               $lines += substr_count($match, PHP_EOL);
           }

       } else if (is_dir($item)) {
           $lines += countLinesOfCode($item);
           continue;
       }       

   }

   return $lines;
}

var_dump(countLinesOfCode(dirname(__FILE__))); // int(31) (works for me)
```

Keep in mine this is counting newlines, not end of line character `;`. For example, the line below will be considered one line...

```
var_dump($files); echo 'something'; exit;
```

It also counts lines without any PHP code, e.g. the below code will be 4 lines...

```
<?php



$a = 3;
```

It also doesn't count the `<?php` or closing (if present).

Let me know if it (a) shouldn't match empty lines, (b) should match semi colons instead (will need to ensure they are not appearing within a string) and/or (c) it should match the opening and closing tag (will be easy as changing `$matches[1]` in the `foreach` to `$matches[0]`).

Comment: Shouldnt be this `(.*?)>` something like `(.*?)\?>`  ?

Comment: @yes123 Yep, making some changes and testing it now :)

Comment: @yes123 Updated. Seemed to work on the sample data I fed it :)

Comment: @alex: man there is a huge problem... It doesn't go recurvise under sub-dir. That's a huge problem. I guess we could change glob to match everything inside the path, and in the foreach if it's a dir (is_dir()) we should go recurisvely into that sub-dir. But i don't have such expierence (anyway +1 for the moment)

Comment: @alex: for the empty line of code and the ; sign. Both aren't a big problem

Comment: To get it to work with subdirectories, match all items in dir, and use `is_dir()` to check for dir, and then recursively call the function. Check for PHP files with `(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'php')`.

Comment: dunno where to make that changes :(

Comment: @yes123 I made it recursive for you :)

Comment: @alex: eheh i saw. we made the code slightly different... i used the substr to get the exstension, but maybe my function doens't work on .PHP exstension and that's a problem... anyway all my files were lowercase so it's fine. Result ~17.000 lines of code. O_O

Comment: @yes123 I prefer to use what PHP gives me :)

Comment: @alex: in ur regex can you explain me what `(?:php)` and `($|\?>)` mean?

Comment: @yes123 It is to match `<?` and `<?php` and to match closing tag or it missing (end of file, which is legal).

Comment: @alex: hm but this: `<\?(?:php)` doesn't match this too: `<??` ? Maybe it better this way: `<\?(php)?`

Answer (score 1):

> #### [PHPLOC](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phploc)
>
> A tool for quickly measuring the size and analyzing the structure of a PHP project.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

recursive version of alex function

```
function countLinesOfCode($path) {
   $lines = 0;
   $files = glob(rtrim($path, '/') . '/*');

   foreach($files as $file) {

       if (is_dir($file)){
            if ($file=='.' || $file=='..')
                continue;

            $lines+=countLinesOfCode($file);
       } else if (substr($file,-4)!='.php')
        continue;

        echo 'Counting on ' . $file .'<br>';    
       $fileContents = file_get_contents($file);
       preg_match_all('/<\?(?:php)?(.*?)(?:$|\?>)/s', $fileContents, $matches);

       foreach($matches[1] as $match) {
           $lines += substr_count($match, PHP_EOL);
       }
   }
   return $lines;
}
```

Comment: I don't think `glob()` ever gives you `.` or `..`.

Comment: I wasn't sure that's why i made the check :D

Answer (score 0):

I made it work based on [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11907581/1287812) and the documentation for [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/recursivedirectoryiterator).

```
$path = realpath( '/path/to/directory' );
$lines = $files = 0;
$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $path ), 
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);
foreach( $objects as $name => $fileinfo )
{
    if ( !$fileinfo->isFile() ) 
        continue;

    if( false === strpos( $name,'.php' ) )
        continue;
        
    $files++;
    $read = $fileinfo->openFile();
    $read->setFlags( SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD );
    $lines += iterator_count( $read ) - 1; // -1 gives the same number as "wc -l"
}
printf( "Found %d lines in %d files.", $lines, $files );
```