# PHP_Count total lines in all files under a given folder

Tags: php

Just wanted to count total number of line from all the files from the folder. following php function helps me to count line num for only particular file. just wondering what is the way to cont total number of lines from the folder.

```
$lines = COUNT(FILE($file));
```

Thank you.!

Comment: If you wanted to count number of pages in the books on the desk - what would you do? Describe the algorithm here. Then replace "desk" with "folder", "book" with "file" and "pages" with "lines".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as one above (salathe's answer), except this one prints the number of lines (now in php7) rather than a bunch of error messages.

```
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new 
RecursiveDirectoryIterator(__DIR__));

$lines = 0;
foreach ($files as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isFile()) {
        continue;
    }
    $read = $fileinfo->openFile();
    $read->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD);
    $lines += iterator_count($read) - 1; // -1 gives the same number as "wc -l"
}

echo ("Found :$lines");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate the directory and count each file and sum them all. And you are using `file()` function, which will load the whole content into memory, if the file is very large, your php script will reach the memory limit of your config.

If you could use external command, there is a solution with one line. (If you are using windows, just omit it.)

```
$total = system("find $dir_path -type f -exec wc -l {} \; | awk '{total += $1} END{print total}'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps:

```
<?php

$line_count = 0;
if ($handle = opendir('some/dir/path')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if (is_file($entry)) {
            $line_count += count(file($entry));
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}

var_dump($line_count);

?>
```

Comment: Likely you've missed check if `$entry` is a file. In that case you wouldn't need to check if it is `.` or `..`

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Standard PHP Library (aka SPL) for DirectoryIterator:

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('/path/to/dir');
foreach($dir as $file ){
  $x += (isImage($file)) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

(FYI there is an undocumented function called iterator_count() but probably best not to rely on it for now I would imagine. And you'd need to filter out unseen stuff like . and .. anyway.)

**or try this:--**

see url :- http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/php-count-files-in-a-directory/

```
$directory = "../images/team/harry/";
if (glob($directory . "*.jpg") != false)
{
 $filecount = count(glob($directory . "*.jpg"));
 echo $filecount;
}
else
{
 echo 0;
}
```

Comment: [`iterator_count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-count.php) is documented, in English at least.

Answer (score 0):

A very basic example of counting the lines might look something like the following, which gives the same numbers as [xdazz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11895087/113938).

```
<?php

$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(__DIR__));

$lines = $files = 0;
foreach ($files as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isFile()) {
        continue;
    }
    $files++;
    $read = $fileinfo->openFile();
    $read->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD);
    $lines += iterator_count($read) - 1; // -1 gives the same number as "wc -l"
}

printf("Found %d lines in %d files.", $lines, $files);
```

See also

- [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/recursivedirectoryiterator)
- [`SplFileInfo`](http://php.net/splfileinfo)
- [`SplFileObject`](http://php.net/splfileobject)
- [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/recursiveiteratoriterator)
- [`iterator_count()`](http://php.net/iterator_count)